# Why does the A320 IR2 MEL OPS procedure suggest to switch to ADR3?

Tags: aircraft-systems, airbus-a320, airbus, inertial-nav-system, mel

The A320 34-10-05B IR2 MEL OPS procedure additionally calls for Air Data switching to FO3. 
When ADR 2 is working fine why replace its data on the FO PFD when only IR data is lost?

Comment: Probably a precaution since it's an ADIRS unit that computes AD and IR data?

Comment: Yes but each part is separate. IR for inertial and ADR air for data. 
If that were the case why have a separate switching for inertial and air data and why not have the ECAM for IR fault also ask for air data switching. Don’t see the point.

Answer (score 5):

Even if ADR and IR perform two independent and separate functions, they are the same hardware object ([example](https://aerospace.honeywell.com/content/dam/aero/en-us/documents/learn/products/navigation-and-radios/brochures/C61-0668-000-000-ADIRS-For-Airbus-May-2007-bro.pdf)). A IR2 malfunction is a malfunction: you do not know, in general, what is causing the problem of IR2 and it can possibly be a common problem (maybe undetected on ground by the ADR2).

For example, in the ADIRS Honeywell manual you can find in the IR FAULT chapter:

> The ADR function of the affected ADIRU **may** possibly still work, even
> if the IR function is not working. Cross comparing air data
> information gives the pilot some idea of the validity of the ADR data
> for that ADIRU.

So you have no guarantee that if IR2 is faulty, then ADR2 works. This is why, for precaution, you switch F/O on ADR3.